# Ternary statement breaking out of contructor

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am writing a vertices class for an android project within Eclipse and within the constructor I am having a run-time bug. Here is the constructor...

```
public Vertices(GLGraphics glGraphics, int maxVertices, int maxIndices, boolean hasColor, boolean hasTexCoords)
{
    this.glGraphics = glGraphics;
    this.hasColor = hasColor;
    this.hasTexCoords = hasTexCoords;
    this.vertexSize = (2 + (hasColor?4:0) + (hasTexCoords?2:0)) * 4;

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(maxVertices * vertexSize);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertices = buffer.asFloatBuffer();

    if(maxIndices > 0)
    {
        buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(maxIndices * Short.SIZE / 8);
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        indices = buffer.asShortBuffer();
    }
    else
    {
        indices = null;
    }
}
```

In this statement:

```
this.vertexSize = (2 + (hasColor?4:0) + (hasTexCoords?2:0)) * 4;
```

I am calculating the size of the vertex in bytes. The problem is that whenever a ternary operation is evaluated, vertexSize remains at 0 and the program breaks out of the constructor at that statement. The ternary operator is not evaluating to it's value depending on whether the condition is true or false. What is going on here?

Comment: breaking out how? Is there a logcat message?, stepping over it in the debugger does what?

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing a Null Pointer Exception. The first operand of the ternary operator cannot be `null`.

When you run this line, `hasColor` must be coming in as null, causing your program to give you a run time error. This will cause your program to end and `vertexSize` will never be assigned.

`this.vertexSize = (2 + (hasColor?4:0) + (hasTexCoords?2:0)) * 4;`

Check your logcat, it should show you that this is the case.

**EDIT**

As @jahroy mentioned, although it would throw an NPE at this line, its probably actually throwing the NPE when its passed into the constructor. If you attempt to cast `null` to a boolean, you will also get an NPE.

Comment: You're probably right, but the NPE would get thrown before the constructor executes (when a null Boolean object attemtps to convert itself to the primitive boolean passed as a parameter).

Comment: Guys, it is a small b boolean, not big B Boolean, it _can't_ be null since as he is using it the hasColor will be the one passed in since it masks the class level one.

Comment: @Kaediil I believe they are considering the possibility that a Boolean object is auto-unboxed for the value of the parameter passed in. This *would* cause an NPE if the Boolean argument is null before the function call.

Comment: @Kaediil - Agreed.  That's why I stated that if it's a NPE situation, the NPE will be thrown before the constructor executes (when an attempt is made to convert a null Boolean to a primitive boolean).

Comment: Of course, we are assuming that the error is an NPE. When the OP posts any error logs, we can confirm this.

Comment: Sure, if it was before the line.  I was going on his statement that it fails on the ternary statement, so it was past the autoboxing, but without more info either case could be true.

Comment: Unfortunately the OP gives us no information... He simply assumes that the ternary operator is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you are trying to do too much in a single line of code. I strongly suggest that you break

```
this.vertexSize = (2 + (hasColor?4:0) + (hasTexCoords?2:0)) * 4;
```

Into about three lines of code:

```
int colorWeight = hasColor ? 4 : 0;
int texCoordWeight = hasTexCoords ? 2 : 0;

this vertexSize = (2 + colorWeight + texCoordWeight) * 4
```

Notice how much easier this is to read. Also, when you get error messages, it is much easier to track down the cause.